# Implement Simple Injector with generic repository

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have some problem to implement SimpleInjector with my generic Repository.

I have an interface `IRepository<T> where T : class` and an abstract class `abstract class Repository<C, T> : IRepository<T> where T : class where C : DbContext` which implements the interface. Finally I have my entity repositories which inherit the abstract class. Here's a concret example:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity);
}


public abstract class Repository<C, T> : IRepository<T> 
    where T : class where C : DbContext, new()
{
    private C _context = new C();
    public C Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
        set { _context = value; }
    }
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
        return query;
    }
    ...
}

public class PortalRepository : Repository<SequoiaEntities, Portal>
{
}
```

In my global.asax.cs file, under Application_Start() function, I added :

```
Container container = new Container();
container.Register<IRepository<Portal>, Repository<SequoiaEntities, Portal>>();
container.Verify();
```

When I launch my project, Simple Injector tries to verify the container and I get an error :

> Additional information: The given type `Repository<SequoiaEntities, Portal>` is not a concrete type. Please use one of the other overloads to register this type.

Is there a way to implement Simple Injector with generic class or I have to pass by specific class?

Comment: You should register not abstract type, but final one: PortalRepository: *container.Register<IRepository<Portal>, PortalRepository>();* The problem with abstract class is that it cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @3615 you should put that as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Register<TService, TImpementation>()` method allows you to specify a concrete type (`TImplementation`) that will be created by Simple Injector when the specified service (`TService`) is requested. The specified implementation `Repository<SequoiaEntities, Portal>` however is marked as `abstract`. This disallows Simple Injector from creating it; abstract classes can not be created. The CLR does not permit this.

You do have a concrete type `PortalRepository` however, and I believe it is your goal to return that type. Your configuration should therefore look as follows:

```
container.Register<IRepository<Portal>, PortalRepository>();
```

Alternatively, you can make use of Simple Injector's batch-registration facilities and register all your repositories in one call:

```
Assembly[] assemblies = new[] { typeof(PortalRepository).Assembly };

container.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), assemblies);
```

Comment: In the second case, `typeof(PortalRepository)', it only for the PortalRepository class but you talk about register all repositories ?

Comment: @DervisFindik the example shows the registration of all repositories within *the same assembly* as where the `PortalRepository` lives.