# Registration of open generic types - type parameter mismatch

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I'm trying to register all implementations of my generic repository as follows:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), new[] { typeof(Repository<>).Assembly });
```

However, the container can't verify my configuration:

> Additional information: The configuration is invalid. Creating the
>   instance for type IErrorLogService failed. The constructor of type
>   ErrorLogService contains the parameter with name 'errorLogRepository'
>   and type IRepository<ErrorLog> that is not registered. Please ensure
>   IRepository<ErrorLog> is registered, or change the constructor of
>   ErrorLogService. Note that there exists a registration for a different
>   type Persistence.Interfaces.Repository.Generic.IRepository<T> while
>   the requested type is
>   Persistence.Interfaces.Repository.Generic.IRepository<Persistence.DataModel.ErrorLog>.

Based on [various SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847409/implement-simple-injector-with-generic-repository), the snippet above should be the way to go. What did I miss?

My repository class:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity { }
```

`IRepository` and `Repository` exists in the same assembly.

An explicit registration of each type works:

```
container.Register<IRepository<ErrorLog>, Repository<ErrorLog>>();
```

Comment: Please provide the links in you question to the various SO threads.

Comment: @Steven Sorry, did my update help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Register(Type openGenericServiceType, IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)` overload you are using states in its documentation:

> Registers all concrete, **non-generic**, public and internal types in the given set of `assemblies` that implement the given `openGenericServiceType` with container's default lifestyle (which is transient by default).

Note the word "non-generic" here. This register overload is meant to batch-register all non-generic implementations of an open-generic service type. Since you have one open-generic implementation, this `Register` method will not find it.

Instead, you should use the `Register(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)` overload, that states:

> Registers that a new instance of  will be returned every time a `serviceType` is requested. If `serviceType` and `implementationType` represent the same type, the type is registered by itself. **Open and closed generic types are supported.**

**TLDR;**

Change your registration to the following:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

You can find more information about this in [Simple Injector's documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/advanced#registration-of-open-generic-types).